# Traefik Ingress Controller on Kubernetes, receiving permissions error

Tags: traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I've rolled out the Traefik Ingress Controller on my AKS Cluster (Kubernetes) on Azure. I've got the TOML file talking to the POD, but I receive the following on the logs:

> ime="2018-12-21T00:09:36Z" level=error msg="Failed to read new
>   account, ACME data conversion is not available : permissions 755 for
>   certs are too open, please use 600" time="2018-12-21T00:09:36Z"
>   level=error msg="Unable to add ACME provider to the providers list:
>   unable to get ACME account : permissions 755 for certs are too open,
>   please use 600"

I have resolved this before in a docker environment where I simply chmod 600 the directory in question. However, I can't do that as I don't have direct access to the underlying storage.

If I open a shell to the container, the system and try to chmod that way the system tells me its a read only filesystem.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add information about Traefik installation? Have you used helm for that (what chart) or you've followed some manual (link)? If you've deployed Traefik using YAML file(s) please provide their content.

Comment: I have resolved this with a crude fix. I've deployed a custom Traefik container which adds the required permissions. I was using a deployment file

Comment: Could you please explain your solution in answer section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rutnet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8715761/rutnet) solved the issue by deploing a custom Traefik container which includes the required permissions.